# Server throws no exception when HTTP Response is sent to Client that died

Tags: java, http, jboss, jax-ws

I have the following situation:

1. Client sends a webservice call (HTTP Request) to the server.
2. Server takes 5 minutes to process the webservice call.
3. In the mean time the Client process is killed.
4. Server processing continues successfully and after 5 minutes sends the webservice result (HTTP Response).
5. Everything goes fine. No exceptions. Of course client does not receive the response.

Is this correct behavior, or should there be an exception on the server?

I'm using JAX-WS on JBOSS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In theory this is correct behavior. HTTP usually uses a tcp/ip connection and TCP allows the client to close the connection but still wait for incoming data. [RFC 793 3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.5)

So from the point of the underlying transport layer the server can not know if the client still can handle the process or not.

HTTP RFC 2616 states if client or server wish to time out they should gracfully close the underlying tcp connection and that both should carefully monitor the underlying connection. It does not exactly specify what the server should do when the client wishes to close the tcp connection. Just to handle it "appropriate".

> When a client or server wishes to time-out it SHOULD issue a graceful
> close on the transport connection. Clients and servers SHOULD both
> constantly watch for the other side of the transport close, and
> respond to it as appropriate. If a client or server does not detect
> the other side's close promptly it could cause unnecessary resource
> drain on the network.
> [From Section 8.1.4 of RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)

If a client dies this could mean 1) an ungraceful timeout on the TCP connection or 2) an graceful close by the client. (Probably depending on if the client dies by accident or gets killed smoothly)

If your server can detect 1) it should stop and log an error. If it can not detect it, continuing to process and trying to respond is appropriate behavior.

If your server detects 2) (what it should) and is already sending (e.g. send the header) it should continue to do so as this is expected behavior for the TCP connection and HTTP gives you the choice. If your server is still processing the request and did not begin to send anything you should stop processing and log an error.

The popular NGINX uses an http 499 Client Closed Request error code for that. See [NGINX error 499](http://marc.info/?l=nginx&m=120127275109824&w=2)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I already thought so. Is there any 'official' documentation backing this up? Something like an RFC document or so? I browsed through the HTTP RFC, but could not find anything about it.